# Unable To Convert JSON Object Into Anything Useable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm not too good with JSON just yet, so please excuse if this is a major rookie mistake. I'm sending a query to a local file that does a cURL to an external site's API and gets a JSON object back. Because I have to pay for x queries to the API, I just copied and pasted one and I'm using it in replace of the cURL. I have the following script:

```
$.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: 'ajax.php?v='+value, //with this being an input value, which is totally irrelevant because I'm not actually doing the cURL query anyway
             dataType: 'json',
             success:function(json){

                 var o_response = json;
                 json = $.parseJSON(json);

                 alert(o_response.toSource());
                 alert(json.toSource());

             },
             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('There appears to be a problem with the information you submitted. Please try again or contact us.');
              }
        });
```

And the PHP in ajax.php looks like this:

```
<?

if (isset($_GET['v']) && $_GET['v'] != '') {

$response = '[{"query":"14-22-25-02-W5","response":{"status":"ok","err":[],"lat":51.152259,"lng":-114.202199,"country":"Canada","province":"AB","city":"Calgary","street":"49 Royal Vista Drive NW","street_prox":78,"address":"49 Royal Vista Drive NW, Calgary, AB","lsd":"14-22-25-2 W5","lsd_border":[[51.150459,-114.199327],[51.150447,-114.205067],[51.154059,-114.205071],[51.154072,-114.199332],[51.150459,-114.199327]],"uwi":"","nts":"","nts_border":[],"utm":"11S 695661E 15670479N","utm_v":"Zone 11, 695661 meters easting, 15670479 meters northing (Southern Hemisphere)"}}]';

echo json_encode($response);

}


?>
```

With $response being exactly the same as what the API gives me.

What I want to do is get the "lat" and "lng" values from it. The first example in my JavaScript file, the "alert(o_response.toSource());" bit makes it into a string, which is nice, but I want an object. The second example "alert(json.toSource());" makes it into an object, but removes the quotes around all the keys. For example, it does this:

```
[{query:"14-22-25-02-W5", response:{status:"ok", err:[], lat:51.152259, lng:-114.202199, country:"Canada", province:"AB", city:"Calgary", street:"49 Royal Vista Drive NW", street_prox:78, address:"49 Royal Vista Drive NW, Calgary, AB", lsd:"14-22-25-2 W5", lsd_border:[[51.150459, -114.199327], [51.150447, -114.205067], [51.154059, -114.205071], [51.154072, -114.199332], [51.150459, -114.199327]], uwi:"", nts:"", nts_border:[], utm:"11S 695661E 15670479N", utm_v:"Zone 11, 695661 meters easting, 15670479 meters northing (Southern Hemisphere)"}}]
```

Notice how "query", "response", "status", "lat", "lng", etc, no longer have quotes around them. I imagine this is the way it's supposed to work. So, then, if I try to get the "response" by doing the following:

```
alert(json.response);
alert(json['response']);
alert(json[1]);
```

All I get is 3 undefined alerts.

I'm obviously missing something. Is it not in the right format? Am I parsing or encoding something I shouldn't be?

Any help would be greatly appreciative.

Thank you.

Comment: You're JSON-encoding a string containing JSON text.  Decoding that results in the original string of JSON.  Don't do that.

Comment: Why are you using json_encode on a string that's already in JSON format? Better question: why are you putting the string in JSON format -- you should call json_encode on an array.

Comment: Follow the comments above, but then watch out for issues of making an ajax call to your localhost (127.0.0.1), some browsers without the right security override configured will fail quietly and not give a error, just no response.  A common issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Guess I still got a bunch to learn about JSON.

Comment: Great idea to work with a local copy while developing rather than wasting your money hitting an API over and over :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response string is already JSON so there's no need to run it through `json_encode`. Simply use the following

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

if (empty($_GET['v'])) {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Missing "v" parameter']);
    exit;
}

echo '[{"query":"14-22-25-02-W5","response":{"status":"ok","err":[],"lat":51.152259,"lng":-114.202199,"country":"Canada","province":"AB","city":"Calgary","street":"49 Royal Vista Drive NW","street_prox":78,"address":"49 Royal Vista Drive NW, Calgary, AB","lsd":"14-22-25-2 W5","lsd_border":[[51.150459,-114.199327],[51.150447,-114.205067],[51.154059,-114.205071],[51.154072,-114.199332],[51.150459,-114.199327]],"uwi":"","nts":"","nts_border":[],"utm":"11S 695661E 15670479N","utm_v":"Zone 11, 695661 meters easting, 15670479 meters northing (Southern Hemisphere)"}}]';
```

On the JS side, jQuery already knows the response payload is JSON so again, there's no need to run `json` through `$.parseJSON`. You can simply access the object literal properties directly, eg

```
json[0].response.lat
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I literally cried with joy. I'll accept this when I can :)

Comment: @KentondeJong I've updated my answer somewhat. Make sure it still works. Take note that I'm using some PHP 5.4 syntax and functions.